# How could msg.sender != tx.origin AND extcodesize(caller) == 0 be true?

Tags: solidity, addresses, assembly

I'm working on a puzzle where `msg.sender != tx.origin`, so the implication is that the `caller` needs to be a contract or at least something in between the calling account.

But `extcodesize(caller) == 0` also needs to be true. So the caller needs to be an address or externally owned account.

How can both of these be true? Can the caller's codesize ever be 0 if not an address/EOA?

Comment: Is `caller` `msg.sender`?

Comment: Should be.  `caller` is assembly so is not loggable.  But `caller` is the calling contract, or at least typically it is.

Comment: Yeah I was just wondering, no idea what the `caller` really means.

Comment: Actually, by the documentation, it's not the "call sender" in case of `delegatecall`. That might be a part of the solution. But don't ask me how.

Answer (score 13):

## All things must have a beginning

I think you're getting called from a contract constructor before it's committed to the chain.

At this point, it will have a (theoretical) address but no code yet in the chain. It will only get code size after the transaction completes and the block is accepted.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the correct answer. If not let me know so I can further assist.